# How to remove first n numeric characters from a string using PHP?

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

I have a string `$str = "4sX3yY4mj2DT9gVOOS0x60onT08lwzLLZBqn8"`.
Now I want to remove the first 5 numeric characters from the string.

How do I do that in php?

Comment: Just remove? Or do you need to know / return the values?

Comment: Just removing them is good

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the limit parameter with [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$str = preg_replace('~\d~', '', $str, 5);
```

Comment: @cale_b: it is the pattern delimiter. Most of the time people uses a slash, but you can use other characters.

Comment: Can I ask why you choose `~` instead of the slash?

Comment: @cale_b: because the slash is a more often used as literal character in patterns than the tilde, and because it doesn't hurt the eyes like the dash `#` *(that can be used to comment the pattern)*

Comment: @cale_b regarding pattern character just check this example http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0288c6968db341c1ce3f0499b7341db8a6e90417

Comment: @PeterDarmis: you can also use: `(\d)`, `<\d>`, `{\d}` ... *(even if it isn't a good idea)*